# fmt = "{:>3}" はどのような意味を持ちますか？

Tags: python, python3

```
fmt = "{:>3}"
```

このコードの意味はどういう事なのか、どなたか教えて下さい。
`fmt` には何が代入されますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

おそらく`format`関数用の書式指定文字列でしょう。
以下のページ等の例とは少し違いますが、3桁の右詰め指定を表していると考えられます。

`fmt`に入るのは変換なり適用なりされた何かではなく、指定された文字列の`{:>3}`そのものだけですね。

[書式指定ミニ言語仕様](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> `>` 利用可能なスペースにおいて、右詰めを強制します (いくつかのオブジェクトにおいてのデフォルト)。

[幅 - 【Python入門】format関数で文字列の書き方](https://qiita.com/Morio/items/b79ead5f881e6551d9e1#%E5%B9%85)

> `>`任意の幅 任意の幅を取り、右詰め
>
> ```
> string1 = '左詰め'
> string2 = '中央寄せ'
> string3 = '右詰め'
>
> print('{0:<10}'.format(string1))
> print('{0:^10}'.format(string2))
> print('{0:>10}'.format(string3))
> ```
>
> 実行結果
>
> ```
> 左詰め       
>    中央寄せ   
>        右詰め
> ```

上記を適用すれば、こんな形になるでしょう。

```
fmt = "{:>3}"

string1='X'

print(fmt.format(string1))

  X
# 2桁の空白とそれに続く`X`が表示される
```